# How to instantiate an interface in JNI or work around it?

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I have started programming an API using java and c++ with jni.
It's supposed to display windows and do all that kind of stuff using WINAPI.
But I ran into a problem which is described below the code.

```
public interface WindowPeer {

    public void setPos(int x, int y);

    public void setSize(int width, int height);

    public void setTitle(String title);

}


public class Window {
    static {
        System.load("library.dll");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window w = new Window();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                w.init();
            }
        }).start();
        while(w.peer == null); // just waiting 'til it was "instantiated"
        w.peer.setTitle("New"); // crashes
    }

    private volatile WindowPeer peer;

    private native void init();
}
```

C++ does this:

```
#include "jni.h"
#include "jniHeader.h"
#include "jni_md.h"

class WindowPeer : public _jobject
{

    public:
    void setTitle(jstring title)
    {
        // setting title of window
    }
    void setSize(jint width, jint height)
    {
        // setting size of window
    }
    void setPos(jint x, jint y)
    {
        // setting position of window
    }

};

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_javaJG_Window_init
  (JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
  {
       // instantiating window peer
       WindowPeer peer;
       jfieldID windowPeerID = env->GetFieldID(windowClass, "peer", "Lcom/sun/peer/WindowPeer;");
       env->SetObjectField(obj, windowPeerID, &peer);
  }
```

Now WindowPeer can't be instantiated in c++; JVM crashes when trying to do anything with WindowPeer.
So I need a way as follows:
Window.java has a method called setTitle(String s), but I need a way to tell c++ that "setTitle" was called because c++ has to change the window title.

Clearly I miss something because some websites said that you can't instantiate interfaces in c++.
So how to do the above described?

Comment: You can't inherit from `jobject` like that.

Comment: More generally you can't define java classes in c++

Comment: I'm rather curious what the end goal is here. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Simply I want an Api that creates windows and buttons. Now I am looking for a way to call c++ functions from Java, without using native functions.

Comment: Native functions are how you call c/c++ functions for Java?

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't want 10 native functions in my class. Just one which establishes a "connection" between Java and c++.